# Topics in Chatter

Tags: chatter

In Chatter, when a user (that has Create and Assign permission to Topics in his profile) writes a post with `#[something]`, a topic is created.
Then when we click on "something" the topic opens containing all the posts that were created with `#[something]`.

Also, the user can add more topics on a post when he press the arrow button (at the top right of the post) and click on Add Topics.

In my environment, the button is not appearing and when I click on "something", an error message appears:

> Topic Not Available

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: are you using `topic on object` feature?

Answer (score 0):

I knew what was happening.
The post is been shared in an unlisted group.
The topics are not supported in these types of groupes.

Thank you